# Access OpenShift template parameter inside Dockerfile

Tags: docker, openshift

Will OpenShift build parameters (with the OpenShift Docker build strategy) be automatically exposed to `Dockerfiles` as Docker build arguments (`ARG`)  or environment variables (`ENV`), or does this need explicit configuration in a `BuildConfig` e.g. in these places:

```
oc explain bc.spec.strategy.dockerStrategy.buildArgs
oc explain bc.spec.strategy.dockerStrategy.env
```

The reason I'm asking is that I have a template with several parameters, no explicit configuration yet, but an apparent situation where some parameters are accessible inside the Dockerfile (as `$VAR)` and others are not (`$VAR` is empty). I would like to understand normal behavior, before I debug my situation further.

**UPDATE** I've now added a `oc explain bc.spec.strategy.dockerStrategy.buildArgs` section for the "missing" parameter to the template like so:

```
strategy:
  type: Docker
  dockerStrategy:
    buildArgs:
    - name: VAR
      value: ${VAR}
```

but its value is still empty inside the built container when I would have expected it to be `true` (because I started the build with `oc new-app ... VAR=true`. So something else must be wrong too.

Comment: What are the ones which are set? In general the answer is that params are not passed automatically to builds in any way. The system does set up some values for things related to the build, but they aren't linked to template params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a side-effect of my perhaps particular way of employing OpenShift's Docker build strategy.

I maintain a separate `Dockerfile` in a file and use a script `patch.sh` for inserting it into the uploaded template. This is convenient, because a `Dockerfile` stored in `oc explain bc.spec.source.dockerfile` needs certain escaping (in YAML representation) and the script takes care of this. If I must update the `Dockerfile` (as happens frequently during development) I just edit the file using verbatim `Dockerfile` syntax and then re-run the script.

The script also takes care of removing certain argument definitions from the `Dockerfile` (e.g. `ARG VAR`) and replacing references to them with references to corresponding OpenShift template parameters (e.g. `$VAR` to `${VAR}`). The idea is for the script to turn a `Dockerfile` that would also be suitable for a stand-along Docker environment into one that can serve OpenShift's Docker build strategy with template parallelization.

The actual error occurred because I had added a new template parameter but not jet adjusted the script accordingly. The situation is now back to normal.

**UPDATE** I've now removed the special logic for manipulating arguments from my patch script and introduced build arguments under `bc.spec.strategy.dockerStrategy.buildArgs` instead. Entries look like this:

```
buildArgs:
- name: VAR
  value: ${VAR}
```

So basically, now the build configuration does the copying (instead of my patch script the substitution).